# No Audio Output Device is installed messagem, but sound card is seen in Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

After some updates were installed (some of those failed to install, in case it is relevant) audio started to behave strangely.
It shows red cross on the speaker icon, and shows message "No Audio Output Device is installed"

First of all, I've checked Device Manager, only to find mt sound card installed normally and message said "This device is working properly". I've tried to install other drivers, but it didn't help.

I also checked Services. Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder are running. I tried to restart them, but no luck.

DxDiag shows that no sound card is installed.

System is Windows 10. Sound Card is Realtek 1150.

P.S. Most of the answers, I managed to find, are talking about situation, where device is shown with exclamation mark in yellow, i.e. particular device  has problem with drivers or has problem starting.

Edit: Just to add a bit more context, I actually don't think it's a driver problem, rather a Windows Audio problem, because I also have NVIDIA HDMI Audio and two webcams with mics installed, and they are not shown in output or recording device selection.

Comment: See this page....https://www.driversupport.com/knowledge-article/how-to-realtek-audio-driver-solutions-for-windows/#driversupport

Comment: @Moab, thanks for your answer! I've already tried reinstalling drivers, even uninstalling device fully and reinstalling, with both windows driver and realtek driver. Device was installed correctly and there was "This device is working properly" message in properties.
Yet still there was no sound and "No Audio Output Device is installed".
For me it seems like a problem with Windows Audio rather than drivers.

Comment: See this [page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/realtek-hd-audio-driver-6018591-whql-dated-11-12/8d606bdc-29a2-4d96-84b5-d64bcc91686b). Follow the link and click on Realtek High Definition Audio (HDA - 32/64 bit) Version 6.0.1.8591 WHQL to download the driver

Comment: @spike_66, thank you! I will try it out once I get home

Comment: @spike_66, I've tried, nothing changed, still "This device is working properly" and  "No Audio Output Device is installed". Doesn't seem like driver is an issue

Comment: On this [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520288/windows-10-fix-sound-problems) Microsoft collects the steps to follow to try to solve sound problems. Give them a try, who ever knows ...

Comment: @spike_66, thank you for suggestion! I've tried most of those, besides those, which require interaction with output devices, since no is visible, no change

Answer (score 0):

To not leave this question hanging in case someone will encounter similar problem.

After trying many suggestions, I decided to reinstall Windows entirely, which actually helped.

List of tried things:

- Update or reinstall Realtek driver, e.g. from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/realtek-hd-audio-driver-6018591-whql-dated-11-12/8d606bdc-29a2-4d96-84b5-d64bcc91686b)
- Going through Microsoft suggestions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520288/windows-10-fix-sound-problems) (thanks, @spike_66, for this and previous)
- Rollback latest updates
- Running System File Check

You could also try to restore system to some previous state, I unfortunately didn't have a point to try this.

Answer (score 0):

This might not count as an answer, but I've had the exact same issue for the last week or two, and I have tried everything you have, as well as restarting services, clearing out windows update cache, checking for Intel SST device (I have AMD so that's a bust) etc.

I can confirm though that rolling back a system restore to before the offending update does solve the issue... until such time that Windows installs it again. I think I have isolated my issue to (strangely enough) a .Net update, namely KB4524100. But it's hard to prove a negative, I just know that it hasn't happened again *yet*.

But for anyone else landing here through googling: My issue wasn't solved through any of the listicles and regular suggestions for "No audio output device is installed", seeing as I had no driver issues in device manager, and several audio devices, and just-in-case updated them all.

Answer (score 0):

If the following registry entry is currently set to a "zero-length binary value", either change it manually or save the following as `fixaudio.reg` and import it, then reboot.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations]
"ConsoleSecurity"=hex:01,00,14,80,9c,00,00,00,a8,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
  00,02,00,88,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,01,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,\
  04,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,bf,03,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,00,\
  00,14,00,89,00,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,13,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,81,00,\
  00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,14,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,bf,03,0f,00,01,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,21,01,00,00,01,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,2b,02,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,01,\
  01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00
```

See https://superuser.com/a/1697593 for a bit more detail.