# Windows Audio Issues - No audio device is installed

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have an issue that has been causing me problems for weeks now.

After a restart my computer says that there no audio device installed and I have no audio.
I have followed all the advice from every thread I can find. I have reinstalled drivers, deleted and reinstalled through device manager, changed the driver to the generic sound one, restarted all the audio services and nothing has worked.

What will get audio back for me is remoting into my laptop from another computer and then it will show remote audio on. Then if I restart windows audio endpoint builder all my audio comes back. I don't understand what is causing it to work and would like to fix it to where that is no longer needed.

Comment: Hi, FenrirUnchained623! Can you please add some more details — A screenshot of your audio device in device manager?

Answer (score 0):

Having struggled with the same issue and attempted solutions, hopefully this fix will also work for you. I didn't try remoting in, but the first similar temporary fix I found was going to `Settings > Sound > Ease of Access audio settings` and toggling "Turn on mono audio". After navigating back to `Sound` my audio devices would reappear.

The permanent fix that worked for me was a registry entry. My `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\ConsoleSecurity` was set to a "zero-length binary value", but it should be the value shown in the reg file below. Either change it manually or save the following as `fixaudio.reg` and import it, then reboot.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations]
"ConsoleSecurity"=hex:01,00,14,80,9c,00,00,00,a8,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
  00,02,00,88,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,01,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,\
  04,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,bf,03,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,00,\
  00,14,00,89,00,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,13,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,81,00,\
  00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,14,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,bf,03,0f,00,01,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,21,01,00,00,01,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,2b,02,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,01,\
  01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00
```

References:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-no-audio-output-devices/517633e1-a6e6-43ab-bd55-4e67d533fc57
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/401440/kb5003173-no-audio-device-installed.html
- https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Latitude-5400-no-sound-after-May-2021-Windows-update/td-p/7878650/page/4
- https://ares.gobien.be/2021/10/windows-10-may-2021-update-can-break-audio-service/